# What's the meaning of directories named "name".d

Tags: linux

I was wondering what the suffix **.d** on directories in a linux environment means
for example:

- init.d
- vhosts.d

thanks a lot :)

Comment: See a discussion of this question at [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-directory-names).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is most often used to denote a directory that contains scripts and or configuration files for the system or a particular service or application

```
/etc/init.d - system service configuration
/etc/logrotate.d - logrorate configuration
...
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is by convention, not by magic. Each program which uses this does it with it's own code in a slightly different way. Sometimes they're loaded in alphabetical order, sometimes not. Sometimes all files in the directory are loaded. Sometimes just `.conf` files, sometimes all files except those without common backup suffixes....

Answer (score 5):

The ".d" suffix should mean to You that one should think twice before placing here any files, because some daemon or program can include all files from that directory in its configuration files. So files placed here need to be in proper format/language etc. Its very useful convention and respecting it may be only good for You :) ...and the letter "d" - I guess it's simple from " **d** irectory"?

Comment: It's more likely to come from daemon ;)

Comment: Actually, I think from "directory" is much more likely. Init daemon for init *scripts*? Maybe. But profile daemon?